# Is it a Null Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Is the following Proof Correct

**Theorem.** Let $(a_n)$ be an arbitrary sequence, If $a_n\to+\infty\ as\ n\to\infty$, then $(\frac{1}{a_n})$ is a null sequence.

**Proof.** Assume that $a_n\to+\infty\ as\ n\to\infty$, the following proposition must then be true
$$\forall C\in\mathbf{R}\exists N\in\mathbf{Z^+}\forall n\in\mathbf{Z^+}(n>N\implies a_n\ge C)\ \ (1)$$
Consider now an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, from $(1)$ we can assume that there exists $N\in\mathbf{Z^+}$ such that 
$$\forall n\in\mathbf{Z^+}(n>N\implies a_n\ge \frac{2}{\epsilon})\ \ (2)$$let $M=N$ and assume for some arbitrary $n\in\mathbf{Z^+}$ that $n>N$ it is then evident that $a_n\ge\frac{2}{\epsilon}$, but then $\frac{1}{a_n}\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon$ it then follows that 
$$\forall \epsilon\in\mathbf{R^+}\exists N\in\mathbf{Z^+}\forall n\in\mathbf{Z^+}(n>N\implies |\frac{1}{a_n}|<\epsilon)\ \ (3)$$ and thus $(\frac{1}{a_n})\to 0\ as\ n\to\infty$

$\blacksquare$

Comment: Yes. It is correct.